# Fully specialized class as template function parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have written two different container classes, which have the same interface but use different member data and algorithms to operate on their members. I also have a template function that takes a container and does some useful calculation:

```
class Container1
{
  // implementation here
};

class Container2
{
  // implementation here
};

template<typename ContainerType>
void my_function(ContainerType const& container, /* other parameters */)
{
 // ...
}
```

What bothers me is the fact that 'my_function' should only accept `Container1` or `Container2`, but this is not expressed by the code, since `ContainerType` can be any type. The function is templated by container type since it does the same thing no matter what is the internal implemetation of container.
I am considering a variant where `Container1` and `Container2` would be full specializations of a template class. Then I could be more specific about the argument of `my_function`:

```
template<typename T>
class Container;

// Tags to mark different container types
struct ContainerType1 { };
struct ContainerType2 { };

template<>
class Container<ContainerType1>
{
  // implementation
};

template<>
class Container<ContainerType2>
{
  // implementation
};

template<typename T>
void my_function(Container<T> const& container, /* other parameters */)
{
}
```

In the first case, the compilation with a wrong template parameter will fail if 'ContainerType' does not have the interface required by `my_function`, which is not very informative. In the second case, I would also get a compiler error (failed template parameter deduction) if I supply anything else than `Container<ContainerType1>` or `Container<ContainerType2>`, but I like it better since it provides a hint about what kind of template parameter is expected.

What are you thoughts about this? Is it a good design idea or not? Do you think it is worth the change in the code? There are many other functions like `my_function` in the code and sometimes it is not obvious what kind of template parameters they expect. What are my other options to make `my_function` more specific? I am aware the existence of Boost Concept Check Library.
For the sake of argument, let's suppose that I don't want to solve the problem by using inheritance and virtual functions.
In case it is relevant to the discussion, the common interface of `Container1` and `Container2` is imposed by using CRTP. There might be more container classes in the future.

Comment: This is one of possible solutions. You can also use `std::enable_if` or explicit template instantiation declaration + definition. Both of these solutions use C++11.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few solutions to this kind of problem.

Your solution (implementing your types as a `template` specialization) is one, but one I don't particularly like.

Another is the CRTP:

```
template<typename T>
struct Container {
  // optional, but I find it helpeful
  T* self() { return static_cast<T*>(this); }
  T const* self() const { return static_cast<T const*>(this); }

  // common code between every implementation goes here.  It accesses itself through self(), never this
};

class ContainerType1: public Container<ContainerType1> {
  // more details
};
class ContainerType2: public Container<ContainerType2> {
  // more details
};
```

that is the core of the CRTP.

Then:

```
template<typename T>
void my_function(Container<T> const& container_, /* other parameters */)
{
  T const& container = *(container.self());
}
```

and bob is your uncle.  As a bonus, this provides a place to put common code.

Another option is a tag traits class that marks the types you want to support, like `iterator_traits`.

```
template<typename T>
struct is_container : std::false_type {};
template<>
struct is_container<ContainerType1> : std::true_type {};
template<>
struct is_container<ContainerType2> : std::true_type {};
```

you can even do SFINAE style pattern matching to detect a base type (like how iterators work).

Now your method can test on `is_container<T>::value`, or do tag dispatching on `is_container<T>{}`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first version is do-able.

At the end of the day, you always have to choose the optimum approach. Second one may look like an overkill although it gets the point across.
If you Container classes will both have a common function (let's say `Container1::hasPackage() or Container2::hasPackage()` and you choose to call it within `my_function` then it straight away puts your point across that the eligibility to call it is that function itself. After going through many such projects you will start reading the templates in a reverse manner - starting from the template definition - to see what least properties are needed qualify a particular class.

Having said all this, perhaps your question was more suited for [`Code Review`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

[*One example I created on ideone*](http://ideone.com/9KtV3y) was using your classes but adding a member variable `name` to them both which is expected by `my_function`. Of course there may be classes that will support `name` but the developer may also burn his fingers a few times to realize the idea behind the function.

Comment: Hi AbhiP, I looked at your example on ideone. Since `my_function` uses the public interface of containers, it will eventually fail to compile with every other class lacking this interface. From this point of view, adding one extra member variable does not have any benefit in my opinion and is equivalent to the original implementation. The compiler will inform me that the object I passed to `my_function` does not have member `name`. But the real question is: how do I express the requirement that the parameter should be of type `Container`?

Comment: Agreed. It is not the greatest benefit and is really a moot point. As I mentioned your first version is fine. My suggestion was to help make the compiler checks stricter.